# What kills count towards "To Pay the Bills" for Maya?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing as Maya and somehow I've never been able to get the challenge "To Pay the Bills" to rank 5 to unlock the [Admiral Asskick](http://www.ign.com/wikis/borderlands-2/Admiral_Asskick) head.

This criteria for this challenge is:

> Kill 1000 enemies while using your Action Skill

As a siren, Maya's action skill only holds one enemy in stasis for a few seconds, allowing her (or others) to shoot them while they are immobilized.

I'm curious as to what all counts as kills towards this challenge. I know that having an enemy phaselocked when you kill them counts, but is it possible to get more than one kill at a time? 1000 kills with Phaselock will take quite a while, if it isn't. There are a few instances that I'm not sure will count towards this challenge, but would definitely speed up the process if they did.

The main three scenarios I can think of are:

- Kills on enemies that *aren't* the target of phaselock during the time it is active
- Other players killing your phaselock target
- Abilities that cause AOE effects on your Phaselock target (like [Helios](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Helios_(Maya)) or [Cloud Kill](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_Kill)) that can kill non-targeted enemies with fire/corrosive DoT

Which (if any) of these will give me progress towards "To Pay the Bills"?

Comment: I believe enemies that are not a target, do not count towards it. Other players killing phaselocked enemies, I cannot confirm, but I imagine it does. And AOE stuff should count, granted they die during the time they are locked, however it may not count afterwards. 

You should be able to track each thing if you single someone out and try different scenarios - although tedious.

Comment: @n_palum The triple negative in your first sentence makes it really hard to understand...

Comment: Edited. http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Challenge You really may have to just kill 1000 enemies with the skill itself honestly... She's probably the hardest to do that with.

Comment: @n_palum that was my initial thought, but it just says "*while* using your Action Skill," so I don't know, hence why I asked.

Comment: I'd say it's a safe bet to say that any enemies you kill/your action skill kills, will count towards the challenge. So if it lasts 3 seconds, you have 3 seconds to kill enemies. Only seems fair since other characters have longer skills which every kill it gets them will count towards the challenge.

Comment: if i am not wrong , one of her skill tree will make skill target explode if killed before skill expired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've finished this challenge with all the characters, and I know for sure I've done it with Maya, because [that's the head I like using](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/To_Pay_The_Bills).

It's my understanding that any kills you get while the skill is active count toward the total. This could be a kill with the skill, a kill with a grenade, a kill with your gun, a melee, whatever. This doesn't have to be on an enemy that is phaselocked.

That being said, I haven't played in a while to test it, and at least some of the resources online seem to think that the actual skill has to get the kill. If that's the case, then you'll want to avoid shooting at the locked target, and definitely play by yourself so that no one else shoots it.

It's easier if you get the skill that increases the phaselock duration ([Suspension](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Suspension)), the skill that causes the lock to move to another target after the first is killed ([Sub-Sequence](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sub-Sequence)), the skill that increases your damage while the lock is active ([Wreck](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Wreck)) (assuming that it doesn't have to be the skill getting the kill), and the skills that add damage to the lock ([Helios](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Helios_(Maya)), [Ruin](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ruin)).